# NSURLSession iOS CodeIgniter don't send POST

Tags: codeigniter, post, swift, nsurlsession

This is the way I launch the http request :

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json",
                                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                "User-Agent": UIDevice.currentDevice().model]

let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://WWWW/login/check"))
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let valuesToSend = ["email": self.email!, "password": self.password!]
var error: NSError?

let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(valuesToSend, options:NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error)
var err: NSErrorPointer?
if error == nil {

    let task = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: data, completionHandler: {data, response, error in

        if error == nil {
            println("DATA == \(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")
            println("response == \(response)")
        }

    })
    task.resume()

} else {
    println("Oups error \(error)")
}
```

And in my php file, I have

```
public function check()
    {
        if($this->input->post('email')) {
            echo json_encode("YES");
        } else {
            echo json_encode("NO");
        }
    }
```

It always return me "NO". Someone know why ?

Comment: I thought `$this->input->post()` was for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests. No?

Comment: Neither $this->input->post() neither $_POST..

Comment: That's my point. The `$_POST` is only for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests, not JSON requests (though the response can be in JSON). I suspect the same. Is true with `$this->input->post()` (tho I'm no CodeIgniter guy, so I'm not qualified to say.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hi. Resolved.**

It depends how you send your data. In my case, it was raw, that's say only with the request body.

So you need to do something like :

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

and data will be an array with your post values.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. I just had to write  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); in order to have a real array in my PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
func JSONParseArray(jsonString: String) -> Array<String> {
    var e: NSError?
    var data: NSData!=jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var jsonObj = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
        data,
        options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0),
        error: &e) as Array<String>
    if e == 0 {
        return Array<String>()
    } else {
        return jsonObj
    }
}

    var bodyData = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password //Post data


    let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "URL to php file")
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
            (response, data, error) in
            var output = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) //Get the output
            var array = self.JSONParseArray(self.output) //The output but in a array
    }
```

And in you php file try using: `$_POST['email']`

and not $this->input->post('email')

Comment: Hi. You're using NSURLConnection and I want use the newer NSURLSession.